# I could not generate the formatted XML using Jaxb2Marshaller

Tags: java, jaxb

According to the Spring Batch document, Spring Batch could generate the formatted xml file, but I failed, all XML elements are generated in one line.

Test steps

1. Download spring-batch-2.1.9.RELEASE-no-dependencies
2. Import spring-*-3.2.0.RC1.jar
3. Import jaxb-ri-2.2.6
4. Run org.springframework.batch.sample.iosample.XmlFunctionalTests

Before running the job, I make below changes on /spring-batch-2.1.9.RELEASE-no-dependencies/spring-batch-2.1.9.RELEASE/spring-batch-samples/src/main/resources/jobs/iosample/xml.xml

```
<bean id="itemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemWriter">
    <property name="resource" ref="outputResource" />
    <property name="marshaller" ref="customerCreditMarshaller2" />
    <property name="rootTagName" value="customers" />
    <property name="overwriteOutput" value="true" />
</bean>
<bean id="customerCreditMarshaller2" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
     <property name="contextPaths">
         <list>
             <value>com.test.domain</value><!-- the package is generated from a XSD -->
         </list>
   </property>
   <property name="marshallerProperties">
        <map>
           <entry key="jaxb.formatted.output"><value type="java.lang.Boolean">true</value></entry>
        </map>
   </property>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get formatted xml output from jaxb in spring?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4882988/how-to-get-formatted-xml-output-from-jaxb-in-spring)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JAXB API (com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.output.IndentingUTF8XmlOutput) supports the formatted XML.

But by default, Spring Batch does not use com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.output.IndentingUTF8XmlOutput to generate the output XML.

So we need to create a StreamResult to let Spring Batch use com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.output.IndentingUTF8XmlOutput to generate the formatted XML.

Comment: I know this is an old topic, but can you provide the xml configuration to declare the StreamResult and/or the IndentingUTF8XmlOutput?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want the xml to read yourself. I don't know about spring batch, but you could use Notepad++, download the XML tools plugin, then use "Pretty print (XML only - with line breaks)".
It's not ideal, but read better than all on one line.

Comment: Hi Danielson, thanks for reply, I want to use spring batch to write formatted xml files, but only can generate the one line xml content.