# Is there an equivalent to StringWriter but with StringBuilder internally in Java?

Tags: java, performance, io

I've noticed that StringWriter uses internally a StringBuffer. But if you don't need that synchronisation overhead is there an equivalent to StringWriter that uses a StringBuilder inside?

Comment: What exactly you want to acheive?..I opine that perfomance difference is very minimal whether you use stringbuffer or stringbuilder. (Again that depends on your application)

Comment: Shameless plug: https://github.com/nablex/utils-io More specifically: IOUtils.newCharBuffer();

Comment: @user3505725 if you are really concerned about performance, you wouldn't use either. ;)  Perhaps a re-circled buffer, perhaps a byte based one if you only need ASCII etc, etc.

Comment: This would be used by an custom logger from the application, and many things will be written, so I guess the performance gain would be visible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you happen to use Apache Commons IO, then you can re-use [StringBuilderWriter](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/output/StringBuilderWriter.html) which is described as follows:

> Writer implementation that outputs to a StringBuilder.
>
> NOTE: This implementation, as an alternative to java.io.StringWriter, provides an un-synchronized (i.e. for use in a single thread) implementation for better performance. For safe usage with multiple Threads then java.io.StringWriter should be used.

Its implementation is also straightforward as expected, so you can pattern from it and implement it yourself without adding a new dependency.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no equivalent that uses a `StringBuilder` in the current standard java API (at least 7, I didn't investigate on 8).

Should the rationale behind your question be the performances, I don't think you have to worry. But should this aspect be critical, you can implement a `StringWriter` class on your own but using a `StringBuilder` to check whether the difference is significant. If yes, keep your own, and otherwise, there's no issue.

Comment: +1 you can copy the existing class, and change it in about 5 minutes.

Comment: @sa_vedem Please, let us know about the result, that's interesting!